# c# how to delete and edit information from selected in listbox?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listbox

```
    string Path = @"C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\Adressbok\Adressbok.txt";

    List<string> sökhistorik;

    //Lista
    List<Person> Personer = new List<Person>();

    //instans
    Person p1 = new Person();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void updateUI()
    {
        lstBox.DataSource = null;
        lstBox.DataSource = Personer;
    }
    private void btnSpara_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p1.Namn = tbxNamn.Text;
        p1.Gatuadress = tbxGatuadress.Text;
        p1.Postnummer = tbxPostnummer.Text;
        p1.Postort = tbxPostort.Text;
        p1.Telefonnummer = tbxTelefonnummer.Text;
        p1.Epost = tbxEpost.Text;

        Personer.Add(p1);

        updateUI();

        SaveToFile();

        tbxNamn.Text = "";
        tbxGatuadress.Text = "";
        tbxPostnummer.Text = "";
        tbxPostort.Text = "";
        tbxTelefonnummer.Text = "";
        tbxEpost.Text = "";
    }
```

I want to edit the selected item from listbox and then edit the information and save it again and then make a delete button and delete the whole information. How do i do it. Im using windows forms c#.

Answer (score 1):

Why don''t you use BindingList instead of List?
BindingList will automatically update your UI based on your source.

Assuming `Person` has a ToString(),

```
// Bind BindingList to Listbox
public class Form1 {
    BindingList<Person> personer = new BindingList<Person>();
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = personer;
    }


// Remove on button click
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        //This automatically updates your listBox
        personer.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
}

// Update on Button click
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        Person p = personer[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        //Update person here
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes but this will not remove lines from my text file in my pc?

Comment: This is only changing the BindingList<Person> object within memory. Any type of file IO that needs to be done you can implement separately.